# Comparing two array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

This is my static values which is having id with names:

```js
var staticValues = [
  { "id": "1", "name": "PEKKA" },
  { "id": "2", "name": "Golem" },
  { "id": "3", "name": "Vigilane" },
  { "id": "4", "name": "SpiderMan" },
  { "id": "5", "name": "Archer" },
  { "id": "6", "name": "SuperMan" }
]
```

This is is my returned value from my method:

```js
var myReturnedValues = [
  [ [ "2", "4" ] ],
  [ [ "5", "5" ] ],
  [ [ "1", "3" ] ],
  [ [ "4", "3" ] ]
]
```

My output needs to be like this:

```js
var myReturnedValues = [
  [ [ "Golem", "SpiderMan" ] ],
  [ [ "Archer", "Archer" ] ],
  [ [ "PEKKA", "Vigilante" ] ],
  [ [ "SpiderMan", "Vigilante" ] ]
]
```

What am trying to do here is I have to compare `staticValues` and `myReturnedValues` and return names with respect to their ids instead of returning only ids alone. I tried some more ways with underscore.js but failed. Can someone give me idea about that?

This is how my method looks like:

```js
var staticValues = [ /* here I have the whole static data */ ];

$scope.getCategories = function() {
    var myReturnedValues = mainSteps.map(x => [x.steps.map(y => y.category)]);
    return myReturnedValues;
}
```

**Code After edited** ,

```js
$scope.getCategories =function(){
                  var myReturnedValues =mainSteps.map(x => [x.steps.map(y => y.category+"\n"+"\n"+"\n")]);
                  //return myReturnedValues;
                  console.log('meeee before',angular.toJson(myReturnedValues));
                  newval = {};
                  $.each(staticValues ,function(i,v) {
                   console.log('meeee staticCategories',angular.toJson(staticValues )); 
                    newval[v.id] = v.name;
                  });


                  $.each(myReturnedValues,function(i,v){
                     $.each(v[0],function(x,t){
                      myReturnedValues[i][0][x] = newval[t];
                    });
                  });
                  console.log('meeee after',angular.toJson(myReturnedValues));
                  return myReturnedValues;
                 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following loops:

```
newval = {};
$.each(staticValues,function(i,v) {
  newval[v.id] = v.name;
});

var myReturedValues = [
  [ [ "2", "4" ] ],
  [ [ "5", "5" ] ],
  [ [ "1", "3" ] ],
  [ [ "4", "3" ] ]
];
$.each(myReturedValues,function(i,v){
   $.each(v[0],function(x,t){
    myReturedValues[i][0][x] = newval[t];
  });
});
```

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/cgk478g8/

Comment: I tried that now, and my output is  [[[null,null]],[[null,null]],[[null,null]]]  ,

Comment: as you can see in my jsfiddle is working, you must have another problem in you code

Comment: why are you wrapping a array in a array `[ [ "2", "4" ] ],`?

Comment: let me check again,

Comment: I edited my code. have a look at that , Still am getting null as output

Comment: you staticValues is not like you provided in the question

Comment: No, staticCategories and staticValues are same only , And that staticCategories having the whole json data as i mentioned above in my question

Comment: i see you use angular.toJson(staticCategories) when you console the data why are you doing this isn't staticCategories = staticValues a valid json?

Comment: No buddy , In my Local machine i used var as "staticCategories" but when asking question here i used "staticValues " . That's all .

Comment: ok i understand `console.log(staticValues)` and paste it here

Comment: [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "PEKKA"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Golem"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Vigilane"
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "SpiderMan"
  },
  {
    "id": "5",
    "name": "Archer"
  },
  {
    "id": "6",
    "name": "SuperMan"
  }
]

Comment: {
  "1": "PEKKA",
  "2": "Golem",
  "3": "Vigilane",
  "4": "SpiderMan",
  "5": "Archer","6":"SuperMan"
}

Comment: and finaly `console.log(myReturedValues)` before the each and after

Comment: [[[null,null]],[[null,null]],[[null,null]]]

Comment: this means that this code is wrong `var myReturnedValues =mainSteps.map(x => [x.steps.map(y => y.category+"\n"+"\n"+"\n")]);`

Comment: hahah...this is Too funny Man...My reason for that error is "\n" . Lol

Answer (score 2):

Start by converting `staticValues` to a `key => value` object:

```
names = {}
staticValues.forEach(obj => names[obj.id] = obj.name);
```

Then iterate `myReturedValues` and replace ids with names as you go:

```js
var staticValues = [
  { "id": "1", "name": "PEKKA" },
  { "id": "2", "name": "Golem" },
  { "id": "3", "name": "Vigilane" },
  { "id": "4", "name": "SpiderMan" },
  { "id": "5", "name": "Archer" },
  { "id": "6", "name": "SuperMan" }
]

var myReturnedValues = [
  [ [ "2", "4" ] ],
  [ [ "5", "5" ] ],
  [ [ "1", "3" ] ],
  [ [ "4", "3" ] ]
]

names = {}
staticValues.forEach(x => names[x.id] = x.name)

res = myReturnedValues.map(sub =>   
    [sub[0].map(id => names[id])]
)

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

With underscore you can try like this:

```js
var staticValues = [
  { "id": "1", "name": "PEKKA" },
  { "id": "2", "name": "Golem" },
  { "id": "3", "name": "Vigilane" },
  { "id": "4", "name": "SpiderMan" },
  { "id": "5", "name": "Archer" },
  { "id": "6", "name": "SuperMan" }
];

var myReturedValues = [
  [ [ "2", "4" ] ],
  [ [ "5", "5" ] ],
  [ [ "1", "3" ] ],
  [ [ "4", "3" ] ]
];
var data = _.chain(myReturedValues).map(function(d) {
  //map the myReturedValues
  return d[0].map(function(id) {
    //use underscore to search in the staticValues and return name
    return _.find(staticValues, function(svalue) {
      return svalue.id == id
    }).name
  });
}).value();

console.log(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ,When i'm trying this it say's  "name undefined " !!!! what may be the problem buddy ?